# MapBox not working with huge amount of Data | Javascript

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, papaparse

I tried to parse a 10Mb CSV file using papa parse, which contains data about longitude and latitude.

I used the step function to plot these points on MapBox.

```
fileInput = async e => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
            Papa.parse(file, 
                {
                    download: true,
                    worker: true,
                    header: true,
                    step: function (row) {
                        let from_lat = parseFloat(row.data.from_lat);
                        let from_long = parseFloat(row.data.from_long);
                        let to_lat = parseFloat(row.data.to_lat);
                        let to_long = parseFloat(row.data.to_long);
                        if ( (!(Number.isNaN(from_lat))) && (!(Number.isNaN(from_long)))  ) {
                        new mapboxgl.Marker()
                        .setLngLat([from_lat,from_long])
                        .addTo(map);
                        }
                        if ( (!(Number.isNaN(to_lat))) && (!(Number.isNaN(to_long)))  ) {
                        new mapboxgl.Marker()
                        .setLngLat([to_lat,to_long])
                        .addTo(map);
                        }
                    },
                });
    }
```

If I reduce the size of data in CSV, MapBox works fine but when I used the 10Mb CSV, No points were plotted on MapBox and the browser(Chrome) crashed.

Comment: Instead of markers, you'd want to convert this to a geojson that can be added as symbol layer and then styled to look like markers.

Comment: ok, thank you so much, that helped me.